# I get a save() is a not a function error mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
exports.clearHours = (req, res, next) => {
    Hour
    .find({ user: req.body.userId })
    .then(hour => {
        for (let i=0;i<hour.length;i++) {
            hour[i].hours = 0;
        }
        return hour.save()
    })
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Working hours have been successfully updated.'});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    })
};
```

I am trying to save the formatted array on the database and I get this error. The updated code is passed properly but when I am trying to save the array it comes up with this error. Any ideas why?

This is my **hour** model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const hourSchema = new Schema ({
    day: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hours: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Hour', hourSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are fetching the document into memory and re-setting the `hour` field to 0, better you can run an update query into the database itself.

On top require mongoose -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Below is `clearHours` method refactored.

```
exports.clearHours = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const query = { 
            user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)
        };
        const update = {
            $set: {
                hours: 0
            }
        };
        await Hour.update(query, update).exec();
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Working hours have been successfully updated.'});
    } catch (err) {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works, the only thing needed to change was instead of Hour.update I need to set it to Hour.updateMany because I needed to update multiple Hour elements.